# Compare dates then match columns

Tags: excel, vba, date-comparison

Sheet1 accumulates jobs with recommendations throughout the year.

Sheet2 accumulates completed recommendations.

Any row on Sheet1 without a match needs to be followed up. Duplications are appearing as highlighted on row 14. Since the job on row 14 took place on 1/24/19, the recommendation could not have been completed prior to that date.

Here is the code I'm using to MatchColums;

```
Sub MatchColums()

Dim i, total, fRow As Integer
Dim found As Range

total = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To total
    answer1 = Worksheets(1).Range("C" & i).Value
    Set found = Worksheets(2).Columns("C:C").Find(what:=answer1) 'finds a match

    If found Is Nothing Then
        Worksheets(1).Range("H" & i).Value = "NO MATCH"
    Else
        fRow = Sheets(2).Columns("C:C").Find(what:=answer1).Row
        Worksheets(1).Range("I" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & fRow).Value
        Worksheets(1).Range("J" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("B" & fRow).Value
        Worksheets(1).Range("K" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("C" & fRow).Value
        Worksheets(1).Range("L" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("D" & fRow).Value
        Worksheets(1).Range("M" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("E" & fRow).Value
        Worksheets(1).Range("N" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("F" & fRow).Value
        Worksheets(1).Range("O" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("G" & fRow).Value

     End If
 Next i

End Sub
```

I added the following code to prevent duplications;

```
Sub CompareDates()

If Sheet1.Range("A1") < Sheet2.Range("A1") Then
    Run "MatchColums"
End If
End Sub
```

I'm not getting any error message, but it seems that my CompareDates macro is not working. I tried running the matchcolums macro first, but again I have the same result as follows;

[image]

Here is a copy of Sheet2
[image]

Comment: Are those actual dates or text that looks like dates? Are they left-aligned? What is in `Range("A1")` on each sheet?

Comment: It is difficult to see what is happening or wrong without a sample of the input. Just a simple view to the code, the issue is that if you have a duplicated date, then, you will get duplicated results. In the cells when you have "NO MATCH" on column H, you have text on column I. It seems to be an unexpected result. Could you upload a sample of the input?

Comment: BigBen, these are formatted dates in all cases.  Yes, they are left justified. A1 on each sheet as a header followed by dates.

Comment: David, Yes, I'll edit my post to add Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

**These two lines do the same thing**

```
Dim i, total, fRow As Integer 

Dim i As Variant, total As Variant, fRow As Integer
```

- To `Dim` as `Integer`

  `Dim i As Integer, total As Integer, fRow As Integer`

---

**This looks like it always evaluate to "1" unless`Column A` has empty cells, so how is your `For` loop functional**

```
`total = Worksheets(1).Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`
```

---

**`Find` is only returning the first match**

```
`Set found = Worksheets(2).Columns("C:C").Find(what:=answer1)`
```

- It doesn't look like you are searching for unique values.  Your sample data has "Last Name" in `Column C` and "Moss" appears at different times in `Shhet1`, but your `Find` function will only return the first occurrence of "Moss" in `Sheet2`.  This means the first "Moss" in`Sheet2` will be written for every "Moss" in `Sheet1`.  So your getting false positives and bad matches.  This is evident in your output, you didn't provide a sample of  `Sheet2` but I know the first occurrence of "Moss" is "Job Number 13774" on "12/18/2018"  because it is written multiple times in `Sheet1`. To solve this, use `Find` with unique values or find every match and compare the the dates, job numbers, etc until you get the correct one.
- You have been qualifying your ranges to the worksheet level but `Rows.Count` is not qualified.

---

**This block can be shortened to one line**

```
`Worksheets(1).Range("I" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & fRow).Value`
`Worksheets(1).Range("J" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("B" & fRow).Value`
`Worksheets(1).Range("K" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("C" & fRow).Value`
`Worksheets(1).Range("L" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("D" & fRow).Value`
`Worksheets(1).Range("M" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("E" & fRow).Value`
`Worksheets(1).Range("N" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("F" & fRow).Value`
`Worksheets(1).Range("O" & i).Value = Worksheets(2).Range("G" & fRow).Value`
```

`Worksheets(1).Range("I" & i  ":O" & i) = Worksheets(2).Range("A" & fRow & ":G" & fRow)`

Comment: Profoundly, thanks for the insight into tidying up my code. Your right, since a customer can have more than one job during a month, or over the year using the last name will not always return a unique match.  However, each customer has only one job per day. Recommendations made for that job are usually done in the following days or weeks, but rarely on the same day as in the case of Moss. This is why I wanted to add a macro for date comparison. Job 13877 dated 1/24/2019 could not have been completed on 12/18/2019. I thought if I added a macro such that

Comment: If the date on Sheet1 Col A was < than the date on Sheet2 Col A then run the match macro. Do you think that will solve this issue of duplicates?

Comment: @airstatdipatch It will help but I do not know if it will be the solution that brings 100% accuracy.  I would still try qualifying against more fields.  The effort is trivial, the performance decrease if negligible, the assurance that you are not relying on a single point if failure will let you sleep better at night.  You'll also be better looking, make more money, and people will like you more.